# How to redirect page if header information is not found in IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, http, iis

I've got an IIS server which serves 4 different websites of subsidiary companies of the parent company.I've changed the hosts file in windows of several computers.These changes were like if user wants to go to www.xxx.com send him to www.yyy.com. What i want to do is if a http request comes with header information of, say , www.yyy.com to my www.xxx.com i want to show a webpage e.g. error.html which says "you are not authorized to view that page".Is it possible to do that in IIS Server because i don't have access to web.config of websites

Example:

```
User types-> www.xxx.com
in hosts file of windows: www.xxx.com is sent to www.yyy.com
in IIS if www.yyy.com header information www.xxx.com display error.page
```

Comment: IMHO, need more details. On the surface this sounds more like a DNS matter than anything - re: why even have `yyy` if it's sole purpose is..?

Comment: well we are restricting some laptop users from accessing public websites when they are not at work and we have changed the hosts file at the laptops when they try to browse to hotmail.com for example they will be redirected thecompany.com for example.What i need is when iis receives thecompany.com request with header of gmail.com it must redirect the user to thecompany.com/error.html